# How to play .mp3 file repeatedly in android?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I wanted to play .mp3 repeatedly say for 5-10 times as once the item is selected, a song should play for 5 times repeatedly.

1. Using SoundPool is not benefit as the song plays only for 5 seconds. I wanted the song to play completely and repeat again.
2. when Setlooping for media player play the song indefinitely.

Is there any possibilities to play song no of times and no of times would be defined programmatically before application starts. Pleas any one help.

```
public class BackgroundAudioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    SoundPool loopChant;
    int itempositionno;
    int soundID, i;
    Uri path;
    Intent playbackServiceIntent;
    BackgroundAudioService instanceService;

    public BackgroundAudioService() {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Background method called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onCreate method called");
        instanceService = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onBind method called");
        int itempositionno = intent.getIntExtra("Itempositionno", 0);
        this.itempositionno = itempositionno;
        if (mp == null ){
            mp = new MediaPlayer();}
        setSongAtPosition(itempositionno);
        return new LocalBinder();
    }

    public void setSongAtPosition(int position){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "setSongAtPosition method called");
        itempositionno = position;
        Uri path = null;
        switch (itempositionno){
            case 0:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.shiva);
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.perumal);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.ganesh);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.muruga);
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.iyyappa);
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hanuman);
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.gayathri);
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.aigiri);
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.saibaba);
                break;
            }
            case 9:{
                path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.om);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.release();
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(BackgroundAudioService.this, path);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(BackgroundAudioService.this);
        if (itempositionno == 1){
            setLoopChant();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onPrepared method called");
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onCompletion method called");
    }

    class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        public BackgroundAudioService getService(){
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "LocalBinder method called");
            return instanceService;
        }

    }

    public void setLoopChant(){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "setLoopChant method called");
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onStartCommand method called");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onDestroy method called");
        mp.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even play a media once. You forgot to call

```
mp.prepareAsync();
```

right after you set the DataSource.

Why do you create the MediaPlayer twice? I recommend moving the setOnPreparedListener to the line after new MediaPlayer().

```
if (mp == null ){
  mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp.setOnPreparedListener(BackgroundAudioService.this);
}
```

and then call prepareAsync after setDataSource. Replace the line:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(BackgroundAudioService.this, path);
```

with

```
mp.setDataSource(path);
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks, I call mp in onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) method. I always get illegalstateexception for setdataresoure. With my code, song is playing fine. BTW, I found myself how to repeat the song without using looping and soundpool.

Comment: @meena-ramesh From the code you posted I cannot see that it would work. The method onPrepared never gets called since you don't call mp.prepareAsync. Why not share your solution for others to learn?

Comment: Jan,  mp.setOnPreparedListener(BackgroundAudioService.this); - When this code runs onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) is called and mp.start is called. There is no need to use mp.prepareAsync separately. "setOnPreparedListener" use separate thread.

Comment: @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onCompletion method called");
            if (itempositionno==0 || itempositionno==1 ||
                    itempositionno==5 || itempositionno==6 || itempositionno==8 ||
                    itempositionno== 9){
                if (i<=2){
                    i++;
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand the MediaPlayer lifecycle. Take a look at the source code of MediaPlayer. mp.setOnPreparedListener does not in any way cause a call to onPrepared. You need to call prepareAsync first.